# SQL Server - Select years only if they fall in the current year or previous year

Tags: sql-server, date

I only want to get dates from the current year, and the year previous. So if it's 2011, I get dates in 2011 and dates in 2010. If it's 2012, I get dates in 2012 and 2011.

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT DATEPART(yyyy, date ) as arc_year 
FROM 
   dbo.sports 
WHERE 
   team_id = '".$id."' 
ORDER BY 
   DATEPART(yyyy, date ) DESC
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to avoid using a function on the column itself so an index can be used.

```
... WHERE date >= DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,getdate()) - 1,0) 
      and date <  DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,getdate()) + 1,0) ...
```

Comment: +1 for not trapping into the obfuscation trap... http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/obfuscation/dates  but be careful with the comparisons, doesn't seem correct on the first sight.

Comment: @Markus - Originally I had the `+1` and `-1` in the wrong place is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

A couple things.  First, you should never write queries that way.  Use parameterized queries.  Yours has "sql injection" written all over it.

Second, the best way to do this is:

```
declare @teamid int = -- some value

select * from sports 
  where (team_id = @teamid)
  and date > DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,getdate()) - 1,0)
```

If the date column can contain values greater than the current year then the query would be:

```
declare @startdate datetime = DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,0,getdate()) - 1,0) 
declare @enddate datetime = DATEADD(year,+1,@startdate)
declare @teamid int = -- some value

select * from sports 
where (team_id = @teamid)
and date BETWEEN @startdate and @EndDate
```

Comment: I assume you mean "you don't want to run the function for each **row** either". I'm not actually sure whether this happens or not. It wouldn't if it was in the `select` list. `select getdate()` returns the same value regardless of how long the query runs for.

Comment: This indicates that the predicate **would not** get repeatedly evaluated. `create table #t (i int); INSERT INTO #t select CHECKSUM(NEWID())%2 from sys.all_columns select i, COUNT(*) from #t group by i; select COUNT(*) from #t WHERE i=CHECKSUM(rand())%2 drop table #t `